# How to set up Micromax 353G wireless modem in 12.10?

Tags: wireless, usb-modem, modem

I bought a Micromax 353G modem which is supported on Ubuntu 10.04 but I use 12.10.

Can you tell me how to run it in 12.10?

Answer (score 0):

First open terminal and run the following command:

lsusb

The out put will look something like this.

Noter here the device ID for your modem. For my case it is 1c9e:9605 from OMEGA TECHNOLOGY. 
Now create a configuration file with above vendor and product id using following command:

sudo gedit /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/1c9e:9605

And add the following line:

DefaultVendor = 0x1c9e
DefaultProduct = 0x9605
TargetVendor = 0x1c9e
TargetProduct = 0x9605
MessageContent="55534243123456788000000080000606f50402527000000000000000000000"

Save and exit to terminal. Now Run the following command:

modprobe usbserial vendor=0x1c9e product=0x9605 
usb_modeswitch -c /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/1c9e\:9605

If commands run without any error, you should see your connection int the network indicator (Just click on it and see name of your mobile broad band is enlisted). You can click on the name and it will connect.
Now if you want a permanent solution of the above problem, so that you don't want to run the above commands in every session you can add the bellow mention lines the /etc/rc.local file. So the command will be automatically execute at the startup.

sleep 10
 modprobe usbserial vendor=0x1c9e product=0x9605
 usb_modeswitch -c /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/1c9e\:9605
 sleep 20
 nmcli nm wwan on
 sleep 10
 nmcli con up id "your connection name here"

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The above mentioned answer only work with Ubuntu 12.04

My problem with the Micromax 3g USB modem finally resolved. Kindly Follow the steps as I mentioned in the following link. It's worked well and good for me.

[Configure Micromax USB 3G modem on Ubuntu 12.10](http://imacify.com/2012/10/how-to-configure-micromax-3g-modem-on-ubuntu-12-10/)

Answer (score 0):

See [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_3f_LWz4WFQ&noredirect=1).

This is the simple and best solution just watch this video.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.